# "You didnt painted the house" or "you didnt paint the house" And why?

Tags: grammaticality, auxiliary-verbs, past-simple

Which of the following is the correct sentence?

> You didn't painted the house.
>
> You didn't paint the house.

If I have to guess the second sentence is correct because *did* is past tense and *painted* also past tense. In a sentence we should not use two past tense? Am I correct?

Comment: When *did* functions as an *auxiliary verb*, the *main verb* should be a bare infinitive(a plain form of a verb).

Comment: Are you self-taught by any chance? Have you ever studied English formally?

Answer (score 7):

In English we can only have one tensed verb in a verb phrase. The auxiliary *DO* is always tensed. It is always either past tense or present tense.

If we use the auxiliary *DO*, the Complement verb phrase will always use a *PLAIN* form of the verb. This is the word you see in the dictionary.

- She didn't PAINT the house.

Notice in the sentence above that because *did* is in the past tense, the verb *paint* cannot be past tense. It is in the plain form. Notice also that the verb *paint* is not present tense. The following sentence is ungrammatical:

- She didn't paint**s** the house. (ungrammatical).

Answer (score 5):

This is very very basic English grammar. Forms of *do* are **always** followed by the plain ("infinitive") form of the verb: the *do* shows the tense, the verb doesn't.

Comment: I actually dont like saying *followed*, because we say *All I did was* not *all I did is*. I confused that when I was kid :)

Comment: Agreed that I oversimplified. I was talking about the auxiliary "do", not the lexical verb "do" (which is not normally followed by any verb). Your examples involve a complex structure with an embedded relative clause.

Comment: Personally, I would also mention the missing apostrophes in the OP's examples.