# "What did you say?" or "What did you said?"

Tags: tense

I was teaching my son and I always get confused which verb I should use, as English is our second language, I asked my son to put the word 'said' in example and he come up with this:

> what did you said?

but know there's something wrong so I come a cross this website, so if anyone is reading this can we say :

I know that we can say "what do you say", but i need to know if we can use "what do you said?"

Comment: It's "what did you say" not "what did you said"

Comment: No, you can't. It is a rule of grammar that when "do" is used as an auxiliary verb, as it is in your example, it must be followed by a plain (infinitival) verb form like "say", not past tense "said".

Comment: This has got to be a duplicate - it's one of the most common questions we get.  But I can't quite find an exact duplicate for it.

Comment: You might find [this question and answer helpful](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/116236/you-didnt-painted-the-house-or-you-didnt-paint-the-house-and-why)

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty basic grammar so your question might be closed, but to form a question you use "do" or "did" + the subject +  the infinitive form of the verb.

> I play tennis -> Do you play tennis?
>
> I ate pizza -> What did you eat?
>
> I went to the store -> Where did you go?

[More on making questions in English](http://esl.about.com/od/grammarforbeginners/a/Questions-In-English.htm)